# javascript eval

Tags: javascript, eval

```
eval('({"suc":true})')
```

The above is wrong,should be:

```
eval('{"suc":true}')
```

Why?

Comment: Isn't it the other way round?

Answer (score 4):

When trying to evaluate the interpreter sees the curly brace and thinks it is a block beginning. Enclosing in parenthesis makes it an expression and initializes an object correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to achieve, but from your examples first is correct and the second throws syntax error.

`eval('({"suc":true})')` is the same as `({"suc":true})` and JavaScript interprets it as:

```
( // <- this states begining of expression
    { // <- this is hash/object literal begining
        "suc": // <- this is property name, given as string
            true // <- this is value
    }
)
```

So it returns new object with `suc` property and associated value `true`.

`eval('{"suc":true}')` is the same as `{"suc":true}` and is interpreted as:

```
{ // <- this is block begining
    "suc": // <- this is label, but incorrect, as it is given as string, not literally
        true // <- this is expression
}
```

If you change `"suc"` to `suc` (without parentheses), then it would work, but it's not the same as first example.

*UPDATE*:

As to why array doesn't need parentheses: there is no other construct in JavaSript which would start with `[` character other than array.

There would be no problem with `{` if it would show up in context which expects value like this:

```
eval('var a = {"succ": true}')
```

It's the same in source code (so not only in eval block): you can't create object using short notation (`{ .. }`) without assigning it to some variable or passing as value (to function, return statement...).

Comment: any idea while array doesn't require the parenthesis: var arr=eval('[true, false']);

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('({"suc":true})')
```

Thats not wrong actually, it will be evaluated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `JSON.parse('{"suc":true}))` instead?